# Best way to load images pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Currently, I am loading all images at the start of the program. Is there a better solution for this? As some images may not be used at all throughout the entire game (I'm currently making a main menu).

Main.py

```
import pygame as pg
from Menu import Menu

pg.init()
"""Displays screen"""
winWidth = 1920
winHeight = 1080
size = (winWidth, winHeight)

win = pg.display.set_mode(size)


"""Load images"""
bg_img = pg.image.load('Pic/td-gui/PNG/menu/bg.png')
title_img = pg.image.load('transtitle.png')
settings_img = pg.image.load('Pic/td-gui/PNG/menu/button_settings.png')
play_img = pg.image.load('Pic/td-gui/PNG/menu/button_play.png')
reg_img = pg.image.load('Pic/td-gui/PNG/menu/button_registration.png')
quit_img = pg.image.load('Custom/Menu/Quit.png')
rope_img = pg.image.load('Pic/td-gui/PNG/menu/rope_small.png')
changeDiff_img = pg.image.load('Custom/Menu/Change_Difficulty.png')
score_img = pg.image.load('Custom/Menu/Scoreboard.png')
selectmap_img = pg.image.load('Custom/Menu/Select_map.png')
tutorial_img = pg.image.load('Custom/Menu/Tutorial.png')



"""Puts loaded images into the correct size"""
bg_img = pg.transform.scale(bg_img,(winWidth, winHeight))
title_img = pg.transform.scale(title_img, (750, 75))
play_img = pg.transform.scale(play_img, (250, 250))
rope_img = pg.transform.scale(rope_img, (27, 290))




clock = pg.time.Clock()

win.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
mainMenu = True
settingsMenu = False
run = True
running = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    pg.display.update()
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
            if not run:
                pg.quit()
    """Places correct images in specified location"""
    title = Menu(winWidth // 2 - 375, winHeight // 2 - 500, title_img)

    if mainMenu:
        reg_button = Menu(winWidth // 2 - 150, winHeight // 2 - 100, reg_img)
        ropeR = Menu(winWidth // 2 - 100, 200, rope_img)
        ropeL = Menu(winWidth // 2 + 70, 200, rope_img)
        scoreboard_button = Menu(winWidth//2 - 330, winHeight//2 + 275, score_img)
        play_button = Menu(winWidth // 2 - 125, winHeight // 2 - 375, play_img)
        reg_button = Menu(winWidth // 2 - 161, winHeight // 2 - 100, reg_img)
        quit_button = Menu(winWidth//2 + 30, winHeight//2 + 275, quit_img)
        changeDiff_button = Menu(winWidth//2 - 330, winHeight//2 + 80, changeDiff_img)
        selectmap_button = Menu(winWidth//2 + 30, winHeight//2 + 80, selectmap_img)
        settings_button = Menu(winWidth - 200, winHeight - 200, settings_img)

        """Draws images in specified location and makes buttons if specified"""
        title.draw_img(win)
        if reg_button.draw_button(win):
            print('Reg button clicked')
        ropeL.draw_img(win)
        ropeR.draw_img(win)
        if scoreboard_button.draw_button(win):
            print("options Clicked")
        if play_button.draw_button(win):
            print("Play Clicked")
        if quit_button.draw_button(win):
            pg.quit()
        if changeDiff_button.draw_button(win):
            print('Change Difficulty button pressed')
        if selectmap_button.draw_button(win):
            print('Select Map button preseed')
        if settings_button.draw_button(win):
            print('Settings button pressed')
            mainMenu = False
            settingsMenu = True
    if settingsMenu:
        win.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
        title.draw_img(win)
```

Menu.py

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()

class Menu():
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.img = img
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        self.clicked = False


    def draw_button(self, win):

        action = False
        #get mouse position
        pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        #check mouseover and clicked conditions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and not self.clicked:
                action = True
                self.clicked = True

        if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            action = False
        #draw image
        win.blit(self.img, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        return action

    def draw_img(self, win):
        win.blit(self.img, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

Say I'm making a music button, which is accessible through the settings button, I would currently load the music button image at the start of the program. Is there a way to make it so the music image would only be loaded once the settings button has been pressed?

Comment: It would be easier for us if you provided clarification and yes please show the code

Comment: You can load them whenever, but what problem are you trying to solve? If you can load all images at the beginning of the program, then I'd suggest doing so. That's usually what you do unless you have a strict memory constraint or many assets. A common thing is to load everything at the start of a "scene". So the menu would be a scene, a game level would be a scene, a cut-scene would be a scene and so on. Different views in the menu *could* be considered different scenes, but that would create a loading time going between the different views. So what are you trying to solve more specifically?

Comment: Im just trying to keep it optimized, is it not a waste of memory to load a image that may never be used in the game, as it will only appear in 1 specific circumstance?

Comment: Yes, that would be a waste but it might be worse if you need to display a image and have to skip frames while you wait for it to load. It's all a balance.

Comment: I once asked this question when I started with Game dev using pygame and yes it is a waste of memory if you load everything at once but on a small game using pygame, I would not worry about it. You could attempt to split your game into 'scenes' as mentioned but having a few PNGs always loaded is perfectly fine. You could also implement a `ResourceCache` to load images when you need them if you really wanted to save some memory

Comment: I'd wrap the main menu into a function of its own, the music submenu into another, etc, and have each function deal with loading the assets it needs. Python's garbage collection should deal with unloading the assets once exiting the function.

Comment: Just remember that there's nothing that's "best" or "optimized" as all you're doing is tradeoffs. If you're trying to optimize for memory, then remember that you're often making your program slower. If you're optimizing for speed, then you're often making your program using more memory. If you are loading things just when you need them, you're going to have a loading time switching between different views in your menu. This is often not something you want as the user expects it to be fast. Switching from the game to the menu, it's more forgiving to have a couple of extra ms.

Comment: As a side note, if you really want to get into Game Dev then I would venture into something like Unity pretty quickly after completing a few small games in Python.

Comment: I disagree that python is bad for game development. Pygame is actually decently performant for 2D games, and the lower-level nature means you learn a lot more than using unity. If you go from python to unity you are downgrading yourself, since pygame is actually closer to games OpenGL roots

Comment: I am currently doing my OCR A level project, as I am in year 13 and haven't bothered starting this until now I am short on time until this is due. I started using unreal engine but quickly realised it was going to take me too long to learn C++ as I had never used it before. As we have used a bit of python in college I thought it would be best to use pygame.

Answer (score 2):

To give a quick and simple overview of what you could do, here's an example. You define an abstract `Scene` class. Then, every "scene" in your game inherits from it. Each scene has a `setup` method that loads everything the scene needs (or might need).

```
import pygame


class Scene:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Create all attributes """

    def setup(self):
        """ Load everything in and initialize attributes """

    def handle_events(self, events):
        """ Handle the events for this scene """

    def update(self, dt):
        """ Run logic """
    
    def render(self, screen):
        """ Draw to the screen """


class Menu(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        """ Create all attributes """
        self.image1 = None
        self.image2 = None
        # ... and so on ...

    def setup(self):
        """ Load everything in and initialize attributes """
        self.image1 = pygame.image.load("my_image1.png")
        self.image2 = pygame.image.load("my_image2.png")
        # ... and so on ...

    def handle_events(self, events):
        """ Handle the events for this scene """

    def update(self, dt):
        """ Run logic """
    
    def render(self, screen):
        """ Draw to the screen """
        screen.blit(self.image1, (0, 0))
        # ... and so on ...


class Game(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        """ Create all attributes """
        self.player  = None
        self.enemies = None
        # ... and so on ...

    def setup(self):
        """ Load everything in and initialize attributes """
        self.player  = Player(position=(100, 100), image=pygame.image.load("player.png"))
        self.enemies = [
            Enemy(position=(200, 400), pygame.image.load("enemy1.png")),
            Enemy(position=(200, 500), pygame.image.load("enemy2.png")),
        ]
        # ... and so on ...

    def handle_events(self, events):
        """ Handle the events for this scene """
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEY_DOWN:
                print('PAM!')

    def update(self, dt):
        """ Run logic """
        self.player.update(dt)
        for enemy in self.enemies:
            enemy.update()
    
    def render(self, screen):
        """ Draw to the screen """
        screen.blit(self.player.image, self.player.position)
        for enemy in self.enemies:
            screen.blit(enemy.image, enemy.position)
        # ... and so on ...
```

Here's roughly how a game loop would look like.

```
def main():
    screen  = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 1024))
    clock   = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True
    scene   = Menu()
    scene.setup()
    while running:
        dt = clock.tick(60)
        events = list(pygame.event.get())
        
        scene.handle_events(events)
        scene.update(dt)
        scene.render(screen)

        # Have some way of determining when to switch scene.
        if should_switch_to_game:
            scene = Game()
            scene.setup()
        elif should_switch_to_menu:
            scene = Menu()
            scene.setup()
        # ... and so on ...
```

This is a basic starting point, but there are other ways to handle the situation, like having an asset manager that dynamically load and unload assets based on usage. However, these are quite complicated and will make development and debugging much harder. It's always best to keep things simple when you can. If you can load all images at the beginning of the program, then I'd suggest doing so.

Also, remember that there's nothing that's "best" or "optimized" as all you're doing is tradeoffs. If you're trying to optimize for memory, then you're often making your program slower. If you're optimizing for speed, then you're often making your program use more memory.

If you are loading things just when you need them, you're going to have a loading time switching between different views in your menu. This is often not something you want as the user expects it to be fast. Switching from the game to the menu, it's more forgiving to have a couple of extra ms. But if you feel you want to go the other way then different views in the menu could be considered different scenes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no it's not a problem to load images that are never used, as long as the images are small. It's better to load them all at once so that the interface never has to wait for loading.

However, if you have a very large amount of images or your images are very big, it might be worth loading some images only when you need them. You could do something like this when you start your music field:

```
def start_music_menu():
    global music_icon # Sorry about the global
    if music_icon is None:
        music_icon = pygame.image.load('...')
```

In this case your interface will freeze while loading the extra image. You can also use threading or asyncio to keep your interface responsive while a image is loading.

Answer (score -3):

Properly use OOP concept make separate class for various loading image and then use them accordingly .

Comment: This is extremely broad and general and doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: If I made a class, where would I call the class, as would it not just continuously load the images every time if inside my main loop?

Comment: make a main executing class in which you have your loop and other extra stuff ,and call the class before making the loop . I know this is extremely broad answer ,but this is the solution , make your code more generalize , try to design your code base accordingly.

Comment: This is way too broad to be considered an answer. There are many OOP-concepts and the main one's (SOLID) doesn't answer the question. *"make separate class for various loading image"* I would consider not helpful or wrong as an image is already a class in pygame and you generally want to keep assets in batches. *"use them accordingly"* **is** the problem OP is trying to solve. If someone asks *"how do I x?"* you can't answer with just *"you do x".*

Comment: Your comment is also too broad as it's applicable to every problem (generalize, design correctly, extra stuff, ...). Your first sentence of the comment is very vague.